# How to determine if a String is not a part of an array and count occurrences?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that takes in a series of items and prices as well as the number of customers and what/how many of the items available was purchased. I was able to figure out the inputs, but I want to know how to print which items were not purchased at all for all the customers, and how many of each item was purchased.

This is what I have so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Integer count of number of items in the store
        int count = scan.nextInt();

        // Create an array to store names and prices of each item
        String[] itemName = new String[count];
        double[] itemPrice = new double[count];

        for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            // Scan name of each item and price
            itemName[i] = scan.next();
            itemPrice[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }

        // Integer count for the number of customers
        int numCustomers = scan.nextInt();
        String[] nameF = new String[numCustomers];
        String[] nameL = new String[numCustomers];
        double[] costs = new double[numCustomers];

        for (int j=0; j<numCustomers; j++) {
            // First and last name of each customer
            nameF[j] = scan.next();
            nameL[j] = scan.next();

            //Number of items bought
            int numItems = scan.nextInt();
            String[] customerItems = new String[numItems];

            for (int k=0; k<numItems; k++) {
                // For each number of items bought, name and quantity
                int numItemBought = scan.nextInt();
                String nameOfItem = scan.next();

                for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
                    if (nameOfItem != itemName[i]) {
                        String msg = "No one bought " + nameOfItem;
                        System.out.println(msg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does the input look like?

Comment: @hev1 I have edited the post with example input/output!

Comment: I've added an answer. Does it work for you?

Comment: @hev1 Yes, it does! I have never used HashMaps, only heard of it but never seen it implemented so looks like I learned a new concept today. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I'm happy to help.

Comment: @hev1 So I've been testing it, but it only works with the specific input example I showed you earlier. It doesn't seem to work for any other inputs. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of such input?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KHN2pGW3 It's similar to the previous one, but with different numbers.

Comment: I've fixed it: https://ideone.com/Vq2rnT

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Could I ask what a HashSet does exactly? What did it change about the program?

Comment: It only stores unique elements, so elements are not overcounted.

Comment: But isn't it essentially supposed to count repeat elements?

Comment: If a single person buys the same item multiple times, using a HashSet will prevent overcounting the number of people that bought an item.

Comment: Oh, I understand! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two `HashMap`s for storing the number of times an item was bought and the number of people that bought it, as well as a `HashSet` on each iteration so that the count of people buying an item will be correct even if the same person bought multiple of the same item. The statistics should only be printed at the end, after all the purchases have been accounted for.

```
final Map < String, Integer > numBought = new HashMap < > ();
final Map < String, Integer > peopleBought = new HashMap < > ();
for (int j = 0; j < numCustomers; j++) {
    // First and last name of each customer
    nameF[j] = scan.next();
    nameL[j] = scan.next();

    // Number of items bought
    final Set < String > vis = new HashSet < > ();
    int numItems = scan.nextInt();
    for (int k = 0; k < numItems; k++) {
        // For each number of items bought, name and quantity
        int numItemBought = scan.nextInt();
        String nameOfItem = scan.next();
        numBought.merge(nameOfItem, numItemBought, Integer::sum); // increase quantity of the item
        if (vis.add(nameOfItem))
            peopleBought.merge(nameOfItem, 1, Integer::sum); // increment number of people who bought this item
    }
}
for (final String item: itemName) {
    final Integer num = numBought.get(item);
    if (num == null) {
        System.out.println("No one bought " + item);
    } else {
        System.out.println(peopleBought.get(item) + " bought " + num + " " + item);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ds5Yzw)